# UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header

Tags: gradle, daemon, unmarshalling, gradle-kotlin-dsl, socketexception

When ever I run backend server in Spring boot, I'm getting this error:

```
Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:236)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.compile(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.incrementalCompilationWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:307)
.
.
.
 at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
.
.
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
[backend]       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
[backend]       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
.
.
.
 Unable to clear jar cache after compilation, maybe daemon is already down: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
[backend]       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[backend] Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
```

Then, I run `gradle build clean` and run backend server again and this issue gets fixed. I'm not sure what's causing this issue.

What's the reason behind this and how can I fix this?

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568702/circleci-2-0-error-unmarshaling-return-header-nested-exception-is